# Select2 border color if select component is required

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm adding border color to input fields but can't apply this to select2 components.

```
input:required.form-control:focus, textarea:required.form-control:focus, select:required.form-control:focus{
    border-color: #FF0000!important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
}
input:required:invalid, textarea:required:invalid, select:required:invalid {border: 1px solid darkorange!important;}
input:required:valid, textarea:required:valid, select:required:valid { border: 1px solid black!important; }
```

This is my select2 codes:

```
<select id="select" required>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').select2();
  });
</script>
```

Just want to make border color of select2 component if it's required. And when something selected in that component (anything but "Select" as you can guess) let the color be black. That's it.

This is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91o3L6yg/) link of my template.

Comment: The original `select` element gets visually hidden - so you can try and format `select:required:invalid` all day long, you simply won't _see_ any of it. What you actually see, is the `span` element inserted directly after the `select` element - so you can use `select:required:invalid + span` to target that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your fiddle code
in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z2k5roLy/1/

those css lines helps

```
select.select2:required + .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  border-color: #FF0000;
}

select.select2:required:valid + .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: This is it. You can't imagine how much I struggled. Thank you so much.